# OpenCV with QT Creator Build error

Tags: qt, opencv, pkg-config

I downloaded qt a while ago and have just now recently started playing around with QT creator.

I am trying to get Opencv integrated using pkg-config.

The pro file is:

```
QT += core gui

TARGET = QTTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

unix: CONFIG+=link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG+=opencv
```

I have tried including two different ways  and tried .

I'm trying to simply run the following

```
cv::Mat* mat;
```

and it gives me 2 errors:
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: id returned 1 exit status

It also gives me a warning.

## warning "This version of Mac OSX is unsupported."

Can anyone help or enlighten me on what to do for fixing this. Any help is greatly appreciated. :-D

Comment: Here's an image also.
http://kevinhampton.net/ErrorScreenShot.png

Comment: I've recently started playing with Qt and OpenCV2 on osx, but had no clue about pkg-config. Currently I just like to libraries: `INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/
LIBS += /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.3.1.dylib
LIBS += /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.3.1.dylib
` and that works for me (not sure if it's of any use with your setup)

Answer (score 0):

The `symbol(s) not found` error means you haven't linked the libraries accessed by the code.
The osx warning is because you're probably using a linux distribution, in which case the libraries will have the .so extension, not .dylib.

Unfortunately I can't test on linux at the moment.
Try to follow a [Linux tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-computer-vision-with-opencv-on-linux), there should be [plenty out there](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=opencv%20qt%20linux&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=opencv%20qt%20linux%20library%20link&oq=opencv%20qt%20linux%20library%20link&gs_l=serp.3...143.1618.1.2721.5.5.0.0.0.0.105.382.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.qERByO89P78&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c013475c1f5d647&biw=1276&bih=683)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be that you have an undefined yet declared slot. (That is an action callback function on a widget. Maybe you accidentally created in the designer a click callback function of a button.)

My error msg was the same and here I have found an answer: [Qt & C++: Error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64, collect2: ld returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370264/qt-c-error-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-collect2-ld-retur/12823374#12823374)