# QConnect find no such slot on QCombobox by Qt Creater

Tags: c++, qt

- I create a window which inherits from `QWidget`
- I set a grid layout to that Window
- I make a function called `handleHeroChange(int index)` in public slot inside that window
- I add a `Qcombobox` to call the function `handleHeroChange(int index)`.

Qtcreator keeps telling:

```
**QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::handleHeroChange(int) in ../Testing/Window.cpp:92**
```

What did i do wrong?

**THE CODE:**

```
//Window.h
    class Window : public QWidget
    {
        QGraphicsPixmapItem* avatar;
        QGraphicsTextItem* heroNameItem;
        QGraphicsTextItem* heroStrItem;
        QGraphicsTextItem* heroDexItem;
        QGraphicsTextItem* herointelItem;
      public:
        Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
      public slots:
        void handleHeroChange(int);
    };

//Window.cpp
    Window::Window(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {

       QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(this);
       QComboBox *comboHeroClass = new QComboBox();
        comboHeroClass->addItem("Witcher");
        comboHeroClass->addItem("Maurander");
        comboHeroClass->setCurrentIndex(1);
        grid->addWidget(comboHeroClass, 2,3,1,1);
        QComboBox::connect(comboHeroClass, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this, SLOT(handleHeroChange(int)));
    }

    void Window::handleHeroChange(int index){
        QPixmap myImage;
        if(index == 0){

        }else if(index == 1){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Post here your header file and write QObject::connect

Comment: @Chernobyl  what do you mean by write QObject::connect? i thought this is already enough: QComboBox::connect(comboHeroClass, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this, SLOT(handleHeroChange(int)));

Comment: Post please header file.

Comment: @Chernobyl Already done sir! please help.

Comment: Since you inherit from `QWidget` which is a `QObject` you can just use `connect(...)`.

Comment: Do you have `Q_OBJECT` macro in your header file?

Comment: @Nejat Already man! it just works. Now it does not works anymore. Qtcreator Keep saying: 
error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 ......
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
```

Add Q_OBJECT macro without semicolon to your class and rebuild your project.

Without this macro moc cannot find your class and doesn't create your slot(and some other things) That's why you get your error: you see your slot but it doesn't exist and you get runtime error

Comment: i just put Q_OBJECT like that and it does not compile. it said:
:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: I never seen this error before so here I can't help you unfortunately. Please see other  answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370264/error-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit Maybe you will find solution, but don't think that when you add macro you did something wrong,no! All classes which use signals and slot requires this macro.

Comment: I told you rebuild project, maybe we don't understand each other but now all fine, so it's good)

Comment: yeah! thanks man. Rebuild not work. I have to go Build and choose qmake.